# Can not change "Open in Terminal" default back to Terminal from iterm2

Tags: terminal, finder

I cannot change the default setting back to Terminal for opening a session directly from Finder (from the path you can display at the bottom). I tried a few different ways to remove iterm2 completely but with no success. I believe that it is a known issue that is still unresolved, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727747/4424636) to [how to uninstall iTerm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483710/how-to-uninstall-iterm2).

Does anyone know where exactly this default setting is stored, so I can just change it directly?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

The file you are looking for is: `~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2`

Move or remove it with

```
sudo mv -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2 ~/Library/Application\ Support/old.iTerm2
```

or

```
sudo rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2
```

respectively.

---

### Long version

To fix the Finder context menu, in order to change the "Open with Terminal" back to the default, there seem to be two main options:

- Rebuild Launch Services database
- Delete the Application Support plist

---

#### Rebuild Launch Services database

One answer (or rather, *workaround*) seems to be to ***rebuild the Launch Services database***.

This is mentioned/discussed in [this post](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/8459#note_241810469) under the Gitlab issue [Does not uninstall completely](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/8459)

> The iTerm context menu items pictured -- along with MEGA, but I don't really care -- disappeared as soon as I attempted to rebuild Launch services using some copypasta scripting from here:
>
> https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/
>
> I ran one of the script which ends with apps u, saw some of the same errors mentioned in the comments and then had to wait a few moments with an unresponsive Finder while stuff happened in the background.

So, following the link to [Launch Services database problems: correcting and rebuilding](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/), there are three (or four) options to rebuild the Launch Services database, in increasing order of "blast radius":

##### Option 1

Just the *user domain* - as suggested in the [workaround posted](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/8459#note_241810469) under the Gitlab issue

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -v -apps u
```

##### Option 2

Three domains – *system*, *local*, and *user*

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -v -apps u,s,l
```

##### Option 3

The *whole* database

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -v -all u,s,l
```

##### Option 4

Older syntax (*user domain* only):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -v -domain u
```

---

##### Additional reference

- [lsregister](https://ss64.com/osx/lsregister.html)

> ```
> Syntax
>      lsregister: [Options] [path...]
>                     [-apps domain[,domain]...]
>                       [-libs domain[,domain]...]
>                           [-all  domain[,domain]...]
> ```
>
> lsregister is not on the system path so run it using the full path as shown in the examples below.
>
> ```
> Options
>   -delete   Delete the Launch Services database file. You must then reboot!
>   -kill     Reset the Launch Services database before doing anything else.
>   -seed     If database isn't seeded, scan default locations for applications and libraries to register.
>   -lint     Print information about plist errors while registering bundles.
>   -lazy n   Sleep for n seconds before registering/scanning.
>   -r        Recursive directory scan, do not recurse into packages or invisible directories.
>   -R        Recursive directory scan, descending into packages and invisible directories.
>   -f        force-update registration even if mod date is unchanged.
>   -u        unregister instead of register.
>   -v        Display progress information.
>   -gc       Garbage collect old data and compact the database.
>   -dump [table]
>             Display full database contents after registration.
>   -h        Display help.
>  
>  
>   -convert  Register apps found in older LS database files
> ```

---

#### Delete the Application Support plist

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055292/4424636) (and looking at what **AppCleaner** also recommends in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67524898/4424636)) to [How to uninstall iTerm2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32483710/4424636), and judging by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483710/how-to-uninstall-iterm2#comment133336127_70055292), if the iTerm2 application bundle has already been removed,  but the **Finder** context menus still remain, then this command alone *should* remove them:

```
sudo rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2
```

Failing that, to manually delete all the context menus *and* application bundle, then the three commands required are:

```
sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
sudo rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2
sudo rm -r /Applications/iTerm.app
```